# elseif value is less than getting value or greater than

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to show echo 2 but its not working

```
$zipcode1 = 07300-011;
  $zipcode= str_replace("-","",$zipcode1);
$zipcode = 07300011;
   if ($zipcode >= 20000000 && $zipcode <= 26600999) { 
     echo '1';
}
   elseif ($zipcode >= 07000001 && $zipcode <= 07399999) { 

     echo '2';
}
else {
    echo 'no value';
    }
```

Please let me know where i am doing wrong. Thank you for the help
Result = 2

Comment: youre comparing integer to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare string with string if the leading 0 of the zipcode is important:

```
$zipcode1 = "07300-011";
$zipcode= str_replace("-","",$zipcode1);
$zipcode = "07300011";
if ($zipcode >= "20000000" && $zipcode <= "26600999") { 
    echo '1';
} elseif ($zipcode >= "07000001" && $zipcode <= "07399999") { 
    echo '2';
} else {
    echo 'no value';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You made two mistakes.

One is that the value assigned to `$zipcode1` is not a string, but rather the result of an arithmetic operation. I'm saying `$zipcode1` is not `"07300-011"`, but rather `07300-011`, which is equal to the [octal number](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) `7300` (`3776` in base 10) minus octal `11` (`9` in base 10), i.e `3776 - 9` which is `3767`.

The second is that you're trying to do a numeric comparison using strings. `"20" > "1000"` is not the same as `20 > 1000`. The first would resolve to `true`, whereas the second would give `false` (which is likely what you want).
To fix this, you have to first convert both of them to numbers. You can either cast them:

```php
((int) $zipcode1) > (int) $zipcode2
```

or you can use the `+` sign instead:

```php
(+$zipcode1) > (+$zipcode2)
```

In both cases, you need to first remove whitespaces and every other non-numeric character from the zipcode.

```php
$zipcode = str_replace([' ', '-'], '', $zipcode);
```

Read the following topics in the php docs for more info:

1. [Numeric Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php)
2. [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: thank you for the answer. so now i need to make  $zipcode= (int)$zipcode2; then if condition if ($zipcode >= 07000001 && $zipcode <= 07399999) {